# rviz pointcloud2 multi-window

Tags: rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to have multi-window for pointcloud2 in rviz?
For camera or image we can directly have additional window as we add it up. But for pointcloud2 it does not work like that.

Best,
Kang

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10292/rviz-pointcloud2-multi-window/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz only has one main rendering window.  There are a few possible work arounds:

1. You could launch a second instance of rviz.
2. You can also create a camera view and set the alpha to zero so you only see the renderings not the image.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0